# Component exposed in ember addon is not recognised in ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon, ember-components

I have an addon that records integration tests for ember:

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/ember-cli-test-recorder

However I find that when I import it into an ember cli project via npm and then use the component it exposes like so in appplication.hbs:

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

{{outlet}}
{{test-recorder currentRouteName=currentRouteName}}
```

I get the following at runtime:

```
`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'test-recorder' could not be found
```

Note that the component works fine in the dummy app and this addon used to work in version 1.10 of ember.

Using ember cli 0.2.5 for both addon and ember project in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ember install ember-cli-test-recorder` solved this for me.

For some reason just running `npm install ember-cli-test-recorder` wasn't enough.